Is there a way to see the history of playwright tests that passed as well as failed in GitLab?

When you view the GitLab pipeline results, you can drill down to see a list of all playwright tests, with the failed tests at the top. You click "View Details", and in that modal, it shows you how many times that test failed in the past 14 days.

I also want to see those same details for the tests that passed, but that modal only shows the most basic detail(name of test, execution time). I know that information has to be available somewhere, because if one of the passing tests happens to fail on a subsequent run then it will also display something like above, with "failed 1 time in last 14 days".
How do I get the test results for Passed tests to display that History line? I expect it's some GitLab configuration I haven't been able to find. I don't believe it would be a playwright config option.

Please ask one question per question. Can you share your current pipeline config, and any relevant test code (test code itself, package.json, sample site and test commands) so folks have a starting point for this? Thanks.
